# Are transgender people born physically different from others?

Tags: human-anatomy, gender, sexuality

Are all children born with only either male or female body parts (other than exceptions), or is there actually a natural third gender with the physical characteristics of both genders, e.g. the child has the genitalia, or reproductive organs, of both sexes?

According to Wikipedia they are only either male or female [when born](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_assignment). They only [feel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_identity) [different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans_woman) later on in life.

Comment: @MattDMo I edited out the reference to breasts and made it more comparable (i.e. male and female genitalia)

Comment: Why all these down votes? I was being told this from a long time that they are physically born different. It is obviously noob's question.

Comment: I don't know why you've tagged me in that comment (I haven't downvoted) but it's probably because you are incorrectly trying to label Transgender and Hermaphroditism as the same thing.

Comment: @GriffinEvo I didn't tag you in that comment. You can see that. Anyway I didn't knew the correct word.

Comment: Seems you did because it flagged my inbox, it only does that if you use "@username" (it also does notifies the author of the original post when you comment)... maybe something glitched. Regardless, I'd guess that's the reason - I can imagine some might find it offensive that your question makes them out to be the same thing.

Comment: @GriffinEvo FYI, if the author of a post writes a comment but does not tag anyone and there is only one other user that has commented (note MattDMo's comment has been deleted), the system assumes it was intended to be in response to the other user, and notifies them automatically. See [How do comment `@replies` work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: @p.s.w.g - Thanks, I'd never noticed it happening before!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The concept of [transgenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transgender) has nothing to do with sexual organs at birth. Transgenders is a concept that has to do with sociology, not biology. See the wiki link.

[intersex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex) (previously called Hermaphroditism) has to do with biology. The wiki link makes a great job at defining intersex.

In short: A transgender person is born anatomically either male or female (with eventually exception of intersex who go on to become transgender) and they then identify themselves to the opposite sex (or a third sex) rather than identifying themselves to their actual anatomic sex.

Note that [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52149/how-is-trangender-female-different-from-normal-female-biologically) is closely related.