# What are the types of human intersexuality?

Tags: sexual-dimorphism

Every *genetically-male human* has a female-like sex organ until about the seventh week of pregnancy<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_differentiation_in_humans#:%7E:text=A%20human%20fetus%20does%20not,a%20male%20or%20a%20female.)</sup>, then, in general, due to male chromosomes' effect → androgens would be produced and cause that organ to change into male sexual organs<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_differentiation_in_humans#:%7E:text=A%20human%20fetus%20does%20not,a%20male%20or%20a%20female.)</sup>.

Such a course may be "biased" (for lack of a better term) towards intersexuality, in each of these contexts:

1. [True hermaphoriditism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_hermaphroditism)
2. [Androgen insensitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgen_insensitivity_syndrome), partial or complete
3. Non androgen insensitivity "feminization" in at least one aspect (for example *gender dysphoria in the apparently genetically-male*)

What are the types of human intersexuality (are these the only types)?

Comment: I suggest adding here clear definitions of what you mean by "sex", "gender", "gender identity", etc. - otehrwise yoru last sentence may be misinterpreted. While the identity and phenotipical features may vary, the genotype is usually unambiguous (unless we account for trisomy).

Comment: it is not clear what your question is. SE communities focus on asking and answering questions - you cannot simply have a discussion on the subject here (not that I would be personally against learning more on the subject).

Comment: @RogerVadim would you say that the question is clearer now?

Comment: Isn't this a bit too general? What do you expect as an answer? - more precisely, can an answer fit into one page?

Comment: @RogerVadim I expect a similar list of a few (I would guess 5, probably not more than 10); I am certain that an answer can fit into one page.

Comment: in other words, you expect a review from an expert rather than an answer to a specific question. I suggest that you do a bit of research (i.e., googling) on your own and pose a more specific question. It will simply increase yoru chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @RogerVadim what you wrote is untrue, I have done a lot of prior research in a that topic and actually asked about what I have found so far which I think is more than enough for asking a question here; I am not looking for a higher chance than there is now.

Comment: Besides, there is nothing wrong in asking in expert's review if the question is useful for general audience and the longevity of the post is plausible.

Comment: you have nothing to prove to me... let's hope that somebody takes time to write a kind fo review that you ask for.

Comment: Hopefully someone here would clear the comment section.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] effectively on this site and [edit] or delete your question accordingly. In particular, your question is a duplicate and lacks sufficient evidence of prior research — this site has [many related posts](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=intersex) and wikipedia resources include articles on the [Quigley scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quigley_scale) and [intersex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex), which includes a relevant list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is sex a spectrum?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/89382/is-sex-a-spectrum)