# Sexual devolpment and sexual organs in humans

Tags: human-biology, literature, embryology, sexual-dimorphism

In an anatomy book from a friend studying medicine (Netter's book), I looked at some elements of sexual development in embryos. From a developmental stance, we can draw some analogous organs that correspond to the same organ earlier in development:

For example:

- Clitoris <=> Penis
- Scrotum <=> Vulva

In this book, there is not much more. Yet, I was wondering whether we could find the counterpart of any organs in the reproductive systems of each sex. There wasn't for example any counterpart described in this book for vagina in males, or for prostate in females.

Has someone any reference to give that list the most counterpart we can find between both sexes?

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer to a related post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/89513/46609)?